# How do you write and run a FastCGI application?

Tags: c++, fastcgi

I'm trying my hand out in unfamiliar waters - C++ and FastCGI. I know a fair bit of C/C++ though I haven't written anything in it for over 5 years, and nothing serious before then. I'm completely new to FastCGI. I read on the FCGI website that there are two interfaces - fcgi_stdio and fcgiapp. fcgi_stdio is a wrapper around fcgiapp, and is aimed at porting legacy cgi apps. Since I'm writing from scratch, I'd like to skip the middle man and use fcgiapp directly.

However I do not see how I can initialize it properly. I know that it can use either Named Pipes or Sockets for communication with the server (I'm writing on Windows at first, and will try Linux later), but there is no initialization function to which I can pass a pipe name or a port number. Neither does it use environment variables, as far as I can tell. I've studied the code but it makes little sense. The few functions which do take some kind of "socket" or "port" parameter usually nullify it at the first line (making me wonder why there was a parameter in the first place).

So... how do you do it? Or is the library just a starting point, an you need extensive tweaking to get it to work?

Comment: You may find this http://www.coastrd.com/fastcgi Quickstart guide (using a newer version of fastcgi libfcgi2.dll) as well as an http://www.coastrd.com/cppecho example a useful starting point.

Comment: Interesting, but I suppose I should have been more specific. I want to write an app on Windows (I prefer to use Visual Studio for development) and then later build it on Linux too. That DLL, while looking nice indeed, only works on Windows.